# how to do pagination using mirage fake data in emberjs?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli-mirage

I am using mirage for creating fake data.

**scenario/default.js**

```
export default function(server) {
  server.createList('product', 48);
  server.loadFixtures();
}
```

Above I am creating 48 products and from controller I am calling

```
this.store.query('product', {
                filter: {
                    limit: 10,
                    offset: 0
                }
            }).then((result) => {
                console.log(result);
            });
```

and in **mirage/config.js**

```
this.get('/products', function(db) {
    let products = db.products;
    return {
      data: products.map(attrs => ({
        type: 'product',
        id: attrs.id,
        attributes: attrs
      }))
    };
  });
```

now my question is, how to load 10 products per page? I am sending in filter 10 as page size and offset means page number.

what changes should be done to config.js to load only limited products?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your handler in mirage/config.js:

```
this.get('/products', function(db) {
    let images = db.images;
    return {
      data: images.map(attrs => ({
        type: 'product',
        id: attrs.id,
        attributes: attrs
      }))
    };
  });
```

You are able to access the request object like so:

```
this.get('/products', function(db, request) {
    let images = db.images;
    //use request to limit images here
    return {
      data: images.map(attrs => ({
        type: 'product',
        id: attrs.id,
        attributes: attrs
      }))
    };
  });
```

Have a look at [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/94683786da92a627571e209e060dce53?openFiles=mirage.config.js%2C) for a full example.
Where the this twiddle has the following:

```
  this.get('tasks',function(schema, request){
    let qp = request.queryParams
    let page = parseInt(qp.page)
    let limit = parseInt(qp.limit)
    let start = page * limit
    let end = start + limit
    let filtered = tasks.slice(start,end)
    return {
      data: filtered
    }
  })
```

You'll just adapt it for your use like this:

```
  this.get('products',function(db, request){
    let qp = request.queryParams
    let offset = parseInt(qp.offset)
    let limit = parseInt(qp.limit)
    let start = offset * limit
    let end = start + limit
    let images = db.images.slice(start,end)
    return {
      data: images.map(attrs => ({
        type: 'product',
        id: attrs.id,
        attributes: attrs
      }))
    }
  })
```

Comment: it is working well. thanks.I chagned the db.images to db.products you can also change it.

Answer (score 1):

An example with `todos`, you can adapt it to your own use case.

```
    // Fetch all todos
    this.get("/todos", (schema, request) => {
        const {queryParams: { pageOffset, pageSize }} = request
        
        const todos = schema.db.todos;
    
        if (Number(pageSize)) {
            const start = Number(pageSize) * Number(pageOffset)
            const end = start + Number(pageSize)
            const page = todos.slice(start, end)
        
            return {
                items: page,
                nextPage: todos.length > end ? Number(pageOffset) + 1 : undefined,
            }
        }
        return todos
    });
```